# parse a url query string into a clojure map

Tags: regex, clojure

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the simplest way to parse URL parameters in Clojure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6591604/whats-the-simplest-way-to-parse-url-parameters-in-clojure)

I'd like to take a string like:

"q=foo+bar&x=14&y=hello"

and turn it into a map like:

{:q "foo+bar", :x 14, :y "hello"}

I'm sure there is an elegant idiomatic solution for such a problem.

Comment: I believe this post will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6591604/whats-the-simplest-way-to-parse-url-parameters-in-clojure

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
(->> (split "q=foo+bar&x=14&y=hello" #"&") 
     (map #(split % #"=")) 
     (map (fn [[k v]] [(keyword k) v])) 
     (into {}))
```